# Как откатить завершённую транзакцию (rollback after commit)?

Tags: sql, oracle, транзакции

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ откатить завершённую транзакцию?

Сделал удаление из таблицы` и фиксировал его:

```
delete from table; 
commit;
```

Теперь хочу откатить зафиксированные изменения.

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ сделать это?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Rollback a committed transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19853150) от участника [@Varun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519755/varun)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/19853150

Answer (score 2):

В общем, нельзя откатить изменения, которые были зафиксированны.

Что можно сделать в этой конкретной ситуации, как один из самых быстрых вариантов, сделать флэшбэк запрос к таблице, из которой были удалены строки, и вставить их обратно.

Обратите внимание, успех этой операции зависит от значения (по умолчанию 900 секунд) параметра [UNDO_RETENTION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/UNDO_RETENTION.html#GUID-D238E854-A2C5-463E-A146-31F61300124E) - минимального периода времени (может изменится автоматически), в течение которого информация об откате изменений (*undo records*) сохраняется в табличном пространстве `UNDO`. То есть, если в данный момент не выполняются другие транзакции с большим количеством изменений, то шанс откатить изменения достаточно высок.

Вот простой ребочий пример:

```
show parameters undo_retention 

NAME           TYPE    VALUE 
-------------- ------- ----- 
undo_retention integer 900   

create table t2 (col) as
    select level from dual connect by level<=3
/
delete from tab
/
3 rows deleted.

commit
/
Commit complete.
```

Записать срез данных на момент времени до фиксации транзакции во временную таблицу, затем вставить удалённые записи:

```
create table tmptab as
    select *                                   
    from tab as of timestamp timestamp'2020-10-06 12:11:00'
/  
Table TMPTAB created.

insert into tab
    select * from tmptab minus
    select * from tab
/
3 rows inserted.

select * from tab
/
       COL
----------
         1
         2
         3
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19853321) от участника [@Nick Krasnov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997660/nick-krasnov)</sub>

Comment: если этот способ не помог (например UNDO уже недоступен), то можно еще попробовать воспользоваться LogMiner - он умеет читать данные из ONLINE и ARCHIVED REDO logs и генерировать  соответствующие SQL_UNDO или сделать восстановление TABLE/TABLESPACE на точку времени до удаления